# SQLLITE-Xamarin Form - How to check if a value already exist

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I looking to check if a value already exists, if exists return true if not false. However, I may be missing something on my logic because is always returning null even if the value exists

sample

```
public bool ExistPref(int userid)
        {
            var result = prefDB.db.Table<notificationsPreferences>().Where(t => t.UserId == userid).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("user exist "+result+userid);
            return result != null;

        }
```

and if the user exist
I would like to update his record otherwise insert the new values

```
public int UpdateNotifications(notificationsPreferences item)
        {

            if (item.UserId != 0)
            {
                return prefDB.db.Update(item);
            }
            
            else
            {
              return  prefDB.db.Insert(item);
```

The issue is here ** the Id comes inside the object item, however for some reason doesn't save the 4 digits id, what gets saved is  for example 4 which I assumed is the times I add this item?/ that's why my result is always false because it is not saving the real id .

```
            }
        }
```

Comment: What type is your item ID and did you tag that as "auto increment"?

Answer (score 1):

> if the user exist I would like to update his record otherwise insert the new values

If you want to insert new record or update record into sqlite, you can take a look the following code:

```
private void insertorupdate(User model)
    {
        var data = _SQLiteConnection.Table<User>();

        var d1 = data.Where(x => x.userId == model.userId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (d1 == null)
        {
            _SQLiteConnection.Insert(model);
            Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Added");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Already Mail id Exist");
             _SQLiteConnection.Update(model);
        }
    }

 public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }      
    public string password { get; set; }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Any`

```
return prefDB.db.Table<notificationsPreferences>().Any(t => t.UserId == userid);
```

Comment: I added a new comment in the code . I think my issue is when I saved the item, is not keeping the real id number that comes with the object --item . it randomly saves a 3 /4